# Semantic segmentation ,accuracy from evaluate-generator is good but prediction looks just okay

Tags: keras

I have question about the accuracy from keras evaluate generator

I would provide my code and the question would follows up:

from model part,at the end of model:

```
o = (Reshape(( outputHeight*outputWidth, n_classes)))(o)
o = (Activation('softmax'))(o)
#create model
model = Model( img_input , o )
```

And the evaluation part:

```
K.set_learning_phase(0)
m = load_model(join(save_weights_path,"model.h5"))
batch_size = 1
test_path = "data/validation"
G =Generator(test_path,test_path,batch_size)

images = glob(join(test_path,"*.jpg"))
steps =len(images)
evaluator= m.evaluate_generator(G,steps = steps ,verbose = 1)

print("Accuracy :",evaluator[1])
```

And I get result:

```
256/256 [==============================] - 10s 41ms/step
Accuracy : 0.7758417576551437
```

And then, I predict:
    #feed data 256 images
    X=Generator()
    #predict
    pr = m.predict( np.array([X]))[0]
    #reshape 
    pr = pr.reshape(( output_height ,  output_width , n_classes ) ).argmax(axis=-1)

The result looks okay to me ,but some of them are not good...

The size of image is 512*512

I wonder does the accuracy returns from evaluate_generator really means

my model predict 512*512*0.77 pixels correctly?

Thanks !

edit:

I just do a single experiment:

I leave only one image in the folder and then

run the evaluate_generator ,the accuracy returns is :

```
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step
Accuracy : 0.5572433471679688
```

while I test it on my own :

```
img_name = glob("*.jpg")
gt_name = glob("*.png")

img = cv.imread(img_name[0])

gt = cv.imread(gt_name[0])

c = (img==gt).all(axis=-1)

total  = img.shape[0]*img.shape[1]

print(np.sum(c)/total)
```

Guess what:

```
0.41905975341796875
```

Comment: I think you should check the `IoU` or `MAP` metrics rather than `Accuracy` for semantic segmentation models

Comment: @Anakin yeah I know,but just curious about the meaning  of acc returns from the generator .Do you have any idea what it means? Thanks

Comment: I expect accuracy to be per-pixel accuracy. Btw, in your small experiment shouldn't`img` be your prediction image?

Comment: I get the prediction first,and pull the prediction and ground truth together to see accuracy.

Comment: @Anakin looks like it not what we think it is ?

Comment: If you have a dominant background class, then maybe remove it from the calculations and see what you get.

Comment: @Anakin  Why do we do that?

Comment: This might explain `The result looks okay to me ,but some of them are not good` because a lot of the accuracy can be coming from matching background pixels. Some segmentation dataset do have a significant black background.

Comment: I found the doc and may be I should use :
m.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=AdamW(weight_decay=weight_decay),
        metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy]) ??

Comment: Yeah you should use `categorical_crossentropy` loss but I am not sure about the accuracy. But might work out.

Comment: @Anakin  was using categorical_crossentropy,the difference is this :
    metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy])
I used ["accuracy"] before..

Comment: Yeah, by accuracy I meant metrics, sorry.

Comment: @Anakin It turns out that i made a stupid mistake that I write it in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was wrong

I saved my segmentation output as jpg file which changes some pixels value

After I find out and save as png file ,the acc is the same as what Keras gives.